# But the Resultant Number Changes Format When the Operation Is Performed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, phpexcel

The operation I am attempting to perform to two separate spreadsheets involves two steps, formatting and linking.

The accounting format on the first sheet displays $ - for whole numbers and $0.00 for non-whole numbers (as far as I can tell).  This problem occurs when I'm adding numbers in the accounting format.   When it adds 3 numbers and the resultant format changes from $ - to $0.00.  All the  addition numbers are whole numbers, but the resultant number changes format when the operation is performed. Which I Can't Explain.

I figured this out when I set my displays of the four figures (3 addition and 1 resultant) to the 30th decimal place to see if what I'm adding are whole numbers, and they are whole numbers. But the 1 resultant reads $ 0.000000000029103830456733700000, which is untrue.  Because of that, the link is also untrue.

Below, is the action of the 1st number formatted properly because it is from the same sheet.  The 2nd number is formatted improperly because it was linked. And the 3rd number is mathematically correct as it is, but it is wrong because of the improper linkage with the 2nd number.
Therefore, after this number is linked and performs any action, for example multiplication or division; the cell highlights where it shouldn't.
Any help would be appreciated…

Comment: Perhaps related: [Numeric precision in Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel)

Comment: I found it… If I just transcated the statement… It seems to work…   =TRUNC(SUM(S$17:S$38),2)